# Caught ClassNotFound exception when load class from downloaded dex file

Tags: java, android, classloader, dexclassloader

I'm trying to implement a hot-fix mechanism in my android app. After googling for a while, here's what I've done:

1. I generated a `dynamic.jar` file with the classes that I want to patch. (I'm using eclipse and ADT)
2. Using `dx --dex --output=patch.jar dynamic.jar`, I managed to create a jar file that contains `classes.dex`
3. In my android code, I loaded the class with DexClassLoader: `new DexClassLoader(patchFile.getAbsolutePath(), outputFolder.getAbsolutePath(), null, getClassLoader().getParent()` (Notice I'm using getParent())
4. I've verified that the `.dex` file is extracted successfully in `outputFolder`
5. I changed the class loader to my custom class loader via reflection. And I've verified the custom class loader is working
6. When I try to load class with `CUSTOM_LOADER.loadClass(className)` I got `ClassNotFoundException`

So I'm wondering what is wrong? I used `DexFile` to list all classes in that `.dex` file and the new class is there. Is it even possible to download a subset of compiled classes from Internet?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is absolutely necessary to make hotfixes? Anyway, which class can it not load -- one of yours? You didn't post the details of the exception. Have you verified that the end result path is correct? It may be possible that the JRE doesn't want to load classes from outside your JAR file.